# How to overide NumPy ndarray attributes / properties?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a class that has `real` and `imag` attributes,

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.real, self.imag))
        
    def conjugate(self):
        return A(self.real, -self.imag)
```

It behaves like a complex number (but in my case, I want to realize a complex associative algebra element (e.g. a quantum operator), which is more general than a complex number, so I can not use the build-in `complex` type.)

```
A(1,2).real  # returns 1
A(1,2).conjugate() # returns (1,-2)
```

However, when I put it in a NumPy array, the `conjugate` function still works as expected, but not the `real` attribute.

```
import numpy

numpy.array([A(1,2)]).real
# returns array([(1, 2)], dtype=object)
# expect: array(1, dtype=object)

numpy.array([A(1,2)]).conjugate()
# returns array([(1, -2)], dtype=object)
# as expected
```

How to fix the class `A` to override NumPy's `real` and `imag` attributes when the class object is in the `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using the built-in `complex` class?

Comment: @Julia in my case, I want to realize a complex associative algebra element, which has its own definition of conjugation, so I can not use the built-in complex class.

Answer (score 0):

Your class, with repr tweaked:

```
In [181]: class A:
     ...:     def __init__(self, real, imag):
     ...:         self.real = real
     ...:         self.imag = imag
     ...: 
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return f"A: {repr((self.real, self.imag))}"
     ...: 
     ...:     def conjugate(self):
     ...:         return A(self.real, -self.imag)
```

make an instance:

```
In [192]: x = A(1, 2)
In [193]: x
Out[193]: A: (1, 2)
In [194]: x.real
Out[194]: 1
In [195]: x.conjugate()
Out[195]: A: (1, -2)
```

Put it in an array along with a couple of other values.  The result is object dtype:

```
In [196]: arr = np.array([x, 1, 1 + 4j])
In [197]: arr
Out[197]: array([A: (1, 2), 1, (1+4j)], dtype=object)
```

Elements of the array:

```
In [198]: arr[0]
Out[198]: A: (1, 2)
```

Array `conjugate` runs the `conjugate` method of each element:

```
In [199]: arr.conjugate()
Out[199]: array([A: (1, -2), 1, (1-4j)], dtype=object)
```

`real` is defined as a property, not a method.  It treats your `A` just as it does the complex element:

```
In [200]: arr.real
Out[200]: array([A: (1, 2), 1, (1+4j)], dtype=object)
In [201]: arr.imag
Out[201]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

Elements themselves have this attribute:

```
In [202]: arr[2].imag
Out[202]: 4.0
In [203]: arr[0].imag
Out[203]: 2
```

With object dtype arrays, `numpy` tries to apply the "appropriate" method or operator to each element.

You didn't define `add`, so we get this error:

```
In [204]: arr + arr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [204] in <module>
    arr + arr
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'A'

In [205]: arr[1:] + arr[1:]
Out[205]: array([2, (2+8j)], dtype=object)
```

In short, you cannot access element attributes as though they were array attributes.  `attributes` are not the same as `methods`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also realized that `real` and `imag` are properties of `ndarray` not attributes. Probably the way to override them is to define a `ndarray` subclass (I posted my attempt below). Any further suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the NumPy document on [Subclassing ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html), I figured out a possible solution, by defining a subclass of `numpy.ndarray` to host the class `A` objects. Then it is possible to override the definition of `real` and `imag`.

```
class As(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = numpy.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj
    
    @property
    def real(self):
        return numpy.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.real,1,1)(self)
    
    @property
    def imag(self):
        return numpy.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.imag,1,1)(self)
```

Now one can construct the object array and realize the expected behavior.

```
As([A(1,2)]).real
# As([1], dtype=object)

As([A(1,2)]).conjugate()
# As([(1, -2)], dtype=object)
```